# Esper discard events

Tags: esper, epl

I have a platform that leverages Esper. However, all events are inserted into the Event table and sent to Esper to process. My rules are specific to only around 10% of the data set but the 90% other data going through the engine is bottlenecking my alerts from firing.

Is there a way to tell Esper to discard events that I don't care about on ingest so I have a smaller stream going through the actual alert / rule processing engine?

Answer (score 0):

The insert-into could be handy for you. For example:

```
insert into FilteredStream select * from UnfilteredStream where ...some filter critera...
```

and

```
// the FilteredStream has the filtered events only
select count(*) from FilteredStream
```

There is an overview of under which conditions Esper holds events in memory at `http://espertech.com/esper/faq_esper.php#keep_in_memory`

Comment: Let's say I have the below.. how are the 2 different?


`insert into FilteredStream select * from UnfilteredStream where device_type = 'test'
select * from FilteredStream where id = 'x'`


VS


`select * from FilteredStream(device_type = 'test' and id = 'x')`

Comment: Explained at http://espertech.com/esper/release-6.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#epl-where-clause